# How can scientists measure chemical composition on other planets?

Tags: atmosphere, planetary-science, atmospheric-chemistry

How can scientists measure chemical composition (oxygen, nitrogen etc) and temperature on other planets without being there?

Answer (score 5):

Scientists can measure the chemical composition of the atmosphere of other planets using spectroscopy.  Each molecule in the atmosphere absorbs and re-radiates at specific frequencies of light that are a function of temperature and unique to the specific type of molecule.  For more information see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterrestrial_atmosphere and http://www.physics.uu.se/research/astronomy-and-space-physics/research/planets/exoplanet-atmospheres/ .